# Aeson Convert Array to Object

Tags: haskell

What is the best way 
Data.Aeson FromJSON instance 
Convert Array to Object:

```
import Data.Aeson

data MixArray = MixArray {                                                                                                                                                                                         
  vStr :: String,                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  vNum :: Int,
  vBool :: Bool                                                                                                                                                                                                  
} deriving Show   

main = do
  jsonStr = ["a",1,true]
  mix <- eitherDecode $ jsonStr :: IO (Either String [MixArray])
  show mix
```

to:

```
MixArray { vStr = "a", vNum = 1, vBool= true}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the `FromJSON` instance for lists and the [`Value`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.3.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Value) type, and then construct your type after pattern matching. If the pattern match fails, the parser will fail.

```
import Data.Text (unpack)

instance FromJSON MixArray where
  parseJSON jsn = do
    [String s, Number n, Bool b] <- parseJSON jsn
    return MixArray { vStr = unpack s, vNum = truncate n, vBool = b }
```